# Transact-SQL: Выборка и сортировка уникальных значений из столбца

Tags: sql-server

У меня проблема. Имеется таблица [Person], один из столбцов которой - город прописки [citizen].
Нужно получить **список уникальных городов проживания, отсортировав по длине названия** населённого пункта.

Если я выполняю следующий код:

```
SELECT DISTINCT citizen FROM Person ORDER BY length(citizen);
```

например, в онлайн редакторе SQL, он **выполняется правильно**.

Но когда я в своей Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio пишу:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [citizen] FROM [dbo].[Person] ORDER BY LEN([citizen])
GO
```

то получаю ошибку:

**Элементы ORDER BY должны входить в список выбора, если указывается SELECT DISTINCT.**



А если пишу:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT [citizen], 
        LEN([citizen]) 
    FROM [dbo].[Person] ORDER BY LEN([citizen])
GO
```

Получаю:

|  | citizen | (Отсутствует имя столбца) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Тула | 4 |
| 2 | Москва | 6 |
| 3 | Воронеж | 7 |
| 4 | Волгоград | 9 |

А, так как мне нужен только первый столбец, я пытаюсь сделать:

```
SELECT [citizen] FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT [citizen], 
        LEN([citizen]) 
    FROM [dbo].[Person] ORDER BY LEN([citizen])
    )
```

но получаю уже другую ошибку:

**Предложение ORDER BY не допускается в представлениях, встроенных функциях, производных таблицах, вложенных запросах и обобщенных табличных выражениях, если вместе с ним не указано предложение TOP, OFFSET или FOR XML.**



Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать правильно и компактно нужный мне запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT [citizen]
FROM [dbo].[Person] 
GROUP BY [citizen]
ORDER BY LEN([citizen])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает именно так, как нужно!